# Connecting with Google Picasa -> Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, picasa

I am looking for various ways to make my application more userfriendly, at this time I use my own functions and graphic library in order to crop images and save them, however I really like Google Picasa for it's userfriendly interface, and allready functions

So I am asking if there is a way to connect Google picasa to my own application, ActiveX ?

If I could also tell google what file to open, and what to store it as would be a great bonus

Comment: Look here: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/picasaweb/overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have a forum

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Picasa-Data-API?pli=1

and an example, but is made with php http://chipsandtv.com/articles/picasa-api

from my knowledge at this moment Google is providing API for their applications based on JSON.

best regards,
Radu