# How do I use Picasa's photo-editing features in my program?

Tags: delphi, image-processing, delphi-xe, picasa

How do I integrate Google Picasa's cropping and brightness- and contrast-adjusting features with my Delphi application? Any of its other features would be a bonus for me.

If it is not possible, I am also looking for good native components that can do about the same job and possibly look nice at the same time as well.

I use Delphi XE 3 and Delphi XE 5. I can use Delphi 7 as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting with Google Picasa -> Delphi 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745096/connecting-with-google-picasa-delphi-7)

Comment: I think this question doesn't ask for connection with Picasa (*"the most important features for me would be the cropping feature, adjust brightness and contrast"*), but for image editing set of controls. But maybe I'm wrong... Plastkort, what is this question about ? Is it about accessing Picasa or image editing controls ?

Comment: i have just seen picasa have this feature for cropping, but it never avtually modifies the image, but saves some info about what it processed the images with.

i think i cananot use picasa, but I will try @ravaut123's answer about it anyway, if it does not work, i will just post a new question without the picasa part and see if someone have any better solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist cloud tools for Delphi from Tms Software

TTMSFMXCloudPicasa: component to access Picasa web albums

[TTMSFMXCloudPicasa](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxcloudpack.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question [Connecting with Google Picasa -> Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745096/connecting-with-google-picasa-delphi-7), look at the Picassa API https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/ and there are some components - http://www.sync-components.com/google-delphi-components/picasa and http://code.google.com/p/delphi-google-api/source/browse/trunk/+delphi-google-api/demos/Picasa?r=12